# How do I force a view in a TableRow to extend wider than the rest of the items in the table?

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a 2-column TableLayout filling the whole width of a fragment, but I want a particular item (a custom progress bar) to be greedy and take up as much width as possible, up to the width of the table itself, like so:

```
_______________________________
|Text1-1|Value1-2 |           |
|Text2-1|Value2-2 |           |
|Text3-1|Value3-2=============|
```

The problem is the other rows are fairly short compared to the area reserved for the table, and I can't get the progress bar to extend beyond the widest point of its designated column.

First I tried putting the progress bar and its associated text view in a LinearLayout with a span of 2:

```
<TableRow>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text 3-1" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_span="2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Value3-2" />

    <ProgressBar
      style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:max="100" />
  </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

The LinearLayout didn't expand beyond the width of "column 2", presumably because there is no "column 3" as all rows have 2 child elements:

```
_______________________________
|Text1-1|Value1-2 |           |
|Text2-1|Value2-2 |           |
|Text3-1|Value3-2=|           |
```

Then I removed the LinearLayout making the progress bar the third child of its TableRow:

```
<TableRow>
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text 3-1" />

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Value3-2" />

  <ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100" />
</TableRow>
```

Now the progress bar appears in "column 3" but only uses an arbitrary short length despite having "fill_parent":

```
______________________________
|Text1-1|Value1-2|           |
|Text2-1|Value2-2|           |
|Text3-1|Value3-2|===        |
```

How do I tell it to use all of the available width that is reserved by the table?

Comment: This is definitely more of a hack since I don't think you can do that naturally with TableLayout, but you could probably setClipChildren="false" and setClipToPadding="false" on both the parent and the child, and then dynamically force the width of the ProgressBar to be equal to the column width + (column_width * percentage), and with left-justified gravity and a width set to wrap_content on its parent, it may be able to extend beyond the screen's boundaries. However, that only applies if the parent Table extends that far as well

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question right. Try to set

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

for your `LinearLayout` in `TableRow`